# Sequelize, findOrCreate + findAll unexpected behavior

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to fetch data from a dog API and I want to add to my database only their temperaments. I tried using some loops and a split to isolate the data and then using
findOrCreate() to add only those who are not already in the DB, after that I use findAll()
to get that info from the DB to send it using expressJS.
The unexpected behavior comes when I go to the route that executes all this and the route
only gives about half of the temperaments (they are 124 and it displays arround 54), then when I refresh the page it shows all 124 of them. The DB gets populated with all the 124 in one go so the problem is with findAll()
This is the function that isolates the temperaments and append them to the DB:

```
module.exports = async () => {
  const info = await getAllDogs();
  info.forEach(async (element) => {
    const { temperament } = element;
    if (temperament) {
      const eachOne = temperament.split(", ");
      for (i in eachOne) {
        await Temperament.findOrCreate({
          where: { name: eachOne[i] },
        });
      }
    }
  });
};
```

And this is the code that gets executed when I hit my expressJS sv to get the info

```
exports.temperaments = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await getTemperaments();  //this function is the above function
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("something gone wrong", error);
  }
  const temperamentsDB = await Temperament.findAll();
  res.json(temperamentsDB);
};
```

So as you can see the last function  executes the function that appends all the data to the DB and then sends it with findAll and res.json()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` is a synchronous method so it doesn't await a result of the async callback. You need to do `for of` in order to get wait for all results:

```js
module.exports = async () => {
  const info = await getAllDogs();
  for (element of info) {
    const { temperament } = element;
    if (temperament) {
      const eachOne = temperament.split(", ");
      for (i in eachOne) {
        await Temperament.findOrCreate({
          where: { name: eachOne[i] },
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```